# Identifying Entry Points to an Area in Network Analyst for Vehicle Access Control

Tags: gis, arcgis-server

In the context of Network Analyst, how can I use the ArcGIS to identify all the junctions or entry points on the road network that vehicles can use to access a specific area, as part of a scenario where I need to prevent cars from entering that area?

I want use the following if possible

```
 ArcGIS Pro, 
 ArcGIS Server with Network analyst extension
```